# Ошибка записи byte[] в базу данных PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Делаю вот так:

```
//Загружаем драйвер
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
System.out.println("Драйвер подключен");

//Создаём соединение
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, name, password);
System.out.println("Соединение установлено");

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO photos(client_id, photo_data) values(?, ?)");
preparedStatement.setLong(1,clientID);
// preparedStatement.setBinaryStream(2,new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData),imageData.length);
preparedStatement.setBytes(2,imageData);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Получаю вот такую ошибку:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: столбец "photo_data" имеет тип bytea[], а выражение - bytea
>     Подсказка: Перепишите выражение или преобразуйте его тип.
>     Позиция: 54

Что не так? `imageData` это `byte[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменяйте тип `photo_data` на `bytea`. Название типа [ByteA](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-TABLE) означает byte array. У вас сейчас поле `photo_data` имеет тип массива байтовых массивов. А вставить в него вы пытаетесь просто последовательность байтов. Естественно, что СУБД ваших попыток не понимает.